# Hibernate causes infinite loop with @ManyToMany bidirectional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have two entities in my project with have a many-to-many relation between them. The relation is represented using a helper mapping table in postgres which contains the relevant ID for each entity, pretty standard.

Let's call the table `bucket_object_mapping` and it has two columns: `bucket_id`, `object_id`.

The bucket class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bucket")
public class Bucket {
   // Some fields omitted here

   @ManyToMany(cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinTable(
      name = "bucket_object_mapping",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bucket_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "object_id")
   )
   private List<Model> models;
}
```

**In the `Model` class I have no mapping to the `Bucket` class (no need for that)**

When I run this simple query:

```
SELECT bucket FROM Bucket bucket WHERE bucket.customerId=:customerId
```

The data is returned fine at first, but then an infinite loop of queries to the `Model` table starts to run and I'm not sure why. Looks like it's happening when I return the result list through a SpringMVC controller. **I do convert the `Bucket` to a DTO but not the `Model`** (It's just that the `Model` entity does not have any reference to the `Bucket` so there's not supposed to be a circular reference problem).

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<BucketDTO> getAllByCustomer(@RequestParam(value = "customerid") final Long customerId) {
  return bucketService.getAllBucketsForCustomer(customerId);
}
```

The code in the service:

```
@Transactional
public List<BucketDTO> getAllBucketsForCustomer(final Long customerId) {
  List<Bucket> buckets = bucketDao.getBucketsForCustomer(customerId);
  List<BucketDTO> result = bucketDtoConverter.toDtoList(buckets);
  return result
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code for your controller?

Comment: @LearningPhase - edited the question. I also added the service method that bridges between the controller and the DAO.

Comment: Show Model.class. Do you have relation to Bucket.class?

Comment: @Victor1125 - no mention of `Bucket` in `Model`

Comment: Do you know what line causes that meaning when you put it in debug mode does that execute the <Bucket> buckets = bucketDao.getBucketsForCustomer(customerId) line normally and it goes into infinite mode in next line. Not sure but why it seems your second line in the service  might be causing it

Comment: @LearningPhase -  It looks like it happens right after the controller returns the result (which makes suspect something with JSON serialization). I split the controller line into 2, first assigning the result to a variable and then returning it. It gets to the line of the `return` and start looping there.

Comment: Do you know how to initialize a chat?

Comment: Never tried it before. I can create a new chat room but is it meant for private conversations?

Comment: nope. just chat about the question as it makes easier then to add comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108187/discussion-between-avi-and-learningphase).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was originated in the `Model`. While `Model` does not have any reference to `Bucket` it does have a reference to another object with a `@OneToMany` annotation (and the referenced object references `Model` with `@ManyToOne`).

I converted everything (Bucket, Model and the 3rd object) to DTOs and now it works. The reason for it to work is because **the infinite loop was caused when the jackson lib tried to serialize the result**. Because there was a bidirectional reference from the `Model` object to another object it got stuck in an infinite loop trying to serialize those. By converting to DTO I made sure that only `Model` holds a reference to the other object so it solves the issue.

You can follow the chat that led to the answer [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108187/discussion-between-avi-and-learningphase)

Answer (score -1):

I thnik you should delete relation from Model (if you have) or add MappedBy. 
When you have relation on `Model.class` and no `@MappedBy` so you create first record on table `bucket_object_mapping` for `Bucket` and second record for `Model`

Comment: I am not sure I exactly understand your answer. But I don't have any mention of `Bucket` in `Model`. Although the relation is bidirectional, it is only needed from the `Bucket` end at the moment. So - no mention of `Bucket` in `Model` entity

Comment: I have thought you have. Ok, so sorry.

Comment: No problem. Appreciate your trying to help.